# ('checkbox').change() running on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm working on a project where I have a checkbox and I want a function to run when the checkbox changes form ticked to unticked or vice versa.

Here is the checkbox:

```
<input class="form-control main_checkbox_class"
       type="checkbox"
       value="1"
       checked="checked"
       id="main_checkbox_id" >
```

And then in my javascript I have:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.main_checkbox_class').change(console.log('hello'));
});
```

However when I run this, on page load 'hello' is printed to the console and then nothing happens when I check or uncheck the check box, I'm not sure why this is happening and any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to happen if u uncheck/check the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the event handler as a function reference. At the moment your code is running on load as you're assigning the *result* of `console.log` to the event handler. Try this:

```
$('.main_checkbox_class').change(function() {
  console.log('hello');
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is the answer, I'm pretty new to javascript and I keep getting tripped up by this. I'll accept after 10 mins.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  $('.main_checkbox_class').change(function() {
    console.log( $(this).is(':checked') );
  });
});
```